Amadeus Enterprice API - MasterPricer Elapsed Flying Time at segment level in response, I cant find the EFT in response
In Amadeus enterprice API, Fare_MasterPricerTravelBoard API, I didnt get the following in response.
<attributeDetails>
    <attributeType>EFT</attributeType>
    <attributeDescription>0600</attributeDescription>
</attributeDetails>

My request payload is,
<soapenv:Body>        
    <Fare_MasterPricerTravelBoardSearch>          
        <numberOfUnit>            
            <unitNumberDetail>                
                <numberOfUnits>1</numberOfUnits>
                <typeOfUnit>PX</typeOfUnit>
            </unitNumberDetail>
            <unitNumberDetail>                
                <numberOfUnits>250</numberOfUnits>
                <typeOfUnit>RC</typeOfUnit>
            </unitNumberDetail>
        </numberOfUnit>
        <paxReference>                                
            <ptc>ADT</ptc>
            <traveller>                                  
                <ref>1</ref>
            </traveller>
        </paxReference>
        <fareOptions>                
            <pricingTickInfo>                    
                <pricingTicketing>                    
                    <priceType>CUC</priceType>
                    <priceType>ET</priceType>
                    <priceType>RP</priceType>
                    <priceType>RU</priceType>
                    <priceType>TAC</priceType>
                </pricingTicketing>
            </pricingTickInfo>
            <conversionRate>                  
                <conversionRateDetail>                    
                    <currency>AUD</currency>
                </conversionRateDetail>
            </conversionRate>
        </fareOptions>
        <travelFlightInfo>
            <cabinId>                          
                <cabin>Y</cabin>
            </cabinId>
            <flightDetail>
                <flightType>N</flightType>
                <flightType>D</flightType>
                <flightType>C</flightType>
            </flightDetail>
        </travelFlightInfo>
        <itinerary>                          
            <requestedSegmentRef>                          
                <segRef>1</segRef>
            </requestedSegmentRef>
            <departureLocalization>                            
                <departurePoint>                                
                    <locationId>MEL</locationId>
                </departurePoint>
            </departureLocalization>
            <arrivalLocalization>                            
                <arrivalPointDetails>                                
                    <locationId>JFK</locationId>
                </arrivalPointDetails>
            </arrivalLocalization>
            <timeDetails>                            
                <firstDateTimeDetail>                                
                    <date>300824</date>
                </firstDateTimeDetail>
            </timeDetails>
        </itinerary>
    </Fare_MasterPricerTravelBoardSearch>
</soapenv:Body>

In the example it is shown as the above details will be provided in response. Refer MasterPricer elapsed flying time at segment level in response section. But Im not getting the expected response.
Am I missing anything?
